# cout string and c_str gives different values in c++

Tags: c++

In my code, I have a string variable named ChannelPacket.
when I print Channelpacket in gdb, it gives following string :
"\020\000B\001\237\246&\b\000\016\000\002\064\001\000\000\005\000\021\002\000\000\006\000\f\001\001\000\000sZK"

But if i print Channelpacket.c_str(), it gives just "\020 output. 
Please help me.

Comment: Avoid putting null chars into std::string!

Comment: @NeilKirk Why? It's guaranteed to work, as long as you don't try to treat it as a C-style string.

Comment: @Angew Because it is confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a pointer to char that's understood to be terminated by a NUL character (`'\0'`).

Since your string contains an embedded `'\0'`, it's seen as the end of the string when viewed as a pointer to char.

When viewed as an actual `std::string`, the string's length is known, so the whole thing is written out, regardless of the embedded NUL characters.

Answer (score 3):

The second byte is a zero, which means the end of the string.  If you want to output the raw bytes, rather than treating them as a null-terminated string, you can't use `cout << Channelpacket.c_str()` - use `cout << Channelpacket` instead.